# Custom Post Type vs. User Page

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, multisite

I'm creating a multisite network for authors and readers and I want each blog author to create a user profile.

Ideally I would do this through a customized user admin area with a bunch of added custom fields, but it seems a bit clumsy and not sure how hard it would be to pull this info into the main site (I was thinking switching to that site, pulling the info, then back).

The other way involved creating a Custom Post Type in the main site and manually creating the content myself and linking to the author's sites (sub sites).

I know this is a general question without specific code, but I think it's an important question.

One implication: I want to assign custom taxonomies to the users and run custom loops usign them (on the main site).

I'm not interested in using BuddyPress because I only really need about ten custom fields and I want the sub blog authors to be able to use any theme they want.

Thanks.

Comment: Pulling the user data in the main site is not that hard using the functions WP provides. Instead of custom fields, you can use `user_meta`.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would just use an author.php template for your authors. To add custom user fields you could hard code them, or use a [plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/extra-user-fields/).

See [the_author_meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_author_meta) and [author templates](http://codex.wordpress.org/Author_Templates) in the Codex.